# How do files in `go run *.go` gain access to functions without an import?

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm following the [Bookshelf tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/go/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) on building web services on Google App Engine.

To start the app the tutorial runs `go run app.go auth.go template.go`. I don't understand how this works. For example, how is the [parseTemplate method](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/getting-started/bookshelf/app/app.go#L36) from [template.go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/getting-started/bookshelf/app/template.go) used in [app.go](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/getting-started/bookshelf/app/app.go) without an import statement for `template.go`?

My understanding is that in a Go project we have an entry point file that has a main method. That file then imports packages to use them internally. What is the advantage of running these three files at once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That example uses a single package, specifically the `main` package to implement everything.

Every package may consist of multiple files, even the `main` package. Inside the package you don't import anything, you can access everything from the package. [Spec: Packages:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages)

> Go programs are constructed by linking together packages. A package in turn is constructed from one or more source files that together declare constants, types, variables and functions belonging to the package and **which are accessible in all files of the same package**. Those elements may be [exported](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) and used in another package.

When the special `main` package is broken into multiple files, that's when you have to list all when launching the app:

```
go run app.go auth.go template.go
```

If the example would be separated into multiple packages, only then would you have to import the other packges from `main` to access them.